# keras model.predict accuracy is lower than both the training and validation accuracy when trained and tested on same data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have created a simple Feed Forward Network in keras (tensorflow backend) and this is my optimizer:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=LEARNING_RATE)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',                               
                  optimizer=sgd,                                            
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm trying to train a model for a binary classification problem so my outputs are either in the form [0,1] or [1,0].

I have a model checkpointer that saved the model after this epoch:

```
8812/8812 [==============================] - 0s 35us/step - loss: 0.0076 - 
acc: 0.9994 - val_loss: 0.0010 - val_acc: 0.9995
```

Afterwards I called `model.predict` on the exact same data the model was trained on and got the following output

```
11016/11016 [==============================] - 0s 22us/step
Classifier accuracy: 0.935003631082
```

I printed the `accuracy` index of the output of `model.predict` and got something that seems wrong. (Note that during training 20% of my data was used as validation so `0.8 * 11016 = 8812`

How can the model only have a 93% accuracy on the data that it previously predicted with 99.9%+ accuracy?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Is it possible that your validation data is accidentally part of your training data, so only the final run is using the last 20% of your data?  This would suggest that your model is overfitting and only getting about 65% correct on data it's never trained on.

Comment: @Stephen I will test this explicitly. In `keras` I'm adding the validation_split = 0.2 keyword argument but I'll manually split the data in two to see if this is happening

Comment: How many epochs did you run to get 0.9994? If you didn't specify it in `fit`, the default parameter will only train the model for 1 epoch and the validation set is not used at all. Then it wouldn't be too surprise to find the data is overfitted.

Comment: Ah I found my issue. It was actually quite subtle. When I get time I'll update this question and answer it

Comment: Hey @Dzhao, I am currently facing the same issue. Would you mind updating this question with your solution. Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps your datasets were being randomly selected.